# Gradle: добавление пакета из корня проекта в war-сборку

Tags: java, gradle, war, gretty

Всем привет. У меня есть пакет в корне проекта, который надо добавить в проект. При дефолтной сборке он туда не попадает. Папка называется "frontend" и там нет java-файлов. Проект собирается при помощи gretty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отдельные папки из корня добавляются так:

```
war {
    from 'frontend/build/'
}
```